# Counting triangles in a graph

Tags: numbers, graph-theory, counting, triangle-count

My professor said that I should find a way to find the number of triangles in a graph. I have a problem what graph should I used but my professor suggested that I must first find a way to count the triangles in a graph. I've searched it through Google and I found that there's an algorithm in counting the triangles in a graph but I don't understand much about it because I'm not a ComSci (Computer Science) student. And I also found that I can count the number of triangles by matrix. (1/6)(A)^3. It's a trace of A. So... what I'm asking right now is another idea of finding the number of triangles in a graph. Thank you if I got an answer!

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach is to visit each node and try each path from it that has length 3. If it end at the start-node it will be a triangle.

This is not optimal considering time consumption, but it is simple.